# How can I add bounties?

Tags: discussion, bounty

How do I add a bounty? I don't see an "Add a bounty" button under the question's comment section. I have 87 reputation.

For example, I would like to add a bounty to this: [Miklos Schweitzer 2014 Problem 8: polynomial inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1056041/miklos-schweitzer-2014-problem-8-polynomial-inequality)

Comment: Some basic information on bounties can also be found [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/bounty/info).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties

> If you don't see the bounty button on a question, one or more of the following applies:
>
> - The question has been asked in the last 48 hours. Give the community a chance to answer your question normally first.